# Wordpress | update_user_meta updates the value, but returns false

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, boolean

The question is simple. I have a phone number that I want to update in the user profile using update_user_meta:

```
$update = update_user_meta( 15, 'billing_phone', '79998887766' );

if ( false === $update ) {
    echo 'not updated';
} else {
    echo 'updated';
}
```

As a result, the phone number is updated successfully, but the function returns false:

```
not updated
```

This function should return (int|bool) Meta ID if the key didn't exist, true on successful update, false on failure.
I can't figure out what the reason is.

Comment: At first sight, you're using `===`, does it make a difference if you use  `== `? [Difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/11987538). Also try `echo gettype($update);`

Comment: Replacing === with == gives the same result, and echo gettype($update); returns boolean. In addition, I care very much about the cleanliness of the wordpress engine and prefer not to use plugins unless absolutely necessary. Therefore, this behavior of the function concerned me.

Comment: Well, just tested your code and it does work so it must go wrong elsewhere. 
You will need to update your question with more details/full code, maybe that's where the solution can be found.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/ also be aware that if the meta value is the same as it was before update_user_meta will also return false.